# Can I add to the list of templates available for the new product widget

Tags: magento2, template, widget

Is it possible to add to the list of available templates for the new products widget?

I would like to custom render a view for my homepage. I have gone into

> Content->Pages->homepage

and have added a **new products** widget. In the widget options, there is a template field. There are 5 available templates.

I believe I can edit the corresponding `<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/widget/new/*.phtml` files but is there a way to create a new template and add it to the widget options in the admin?

Comment: Which version of magento you are using?

Comment: I'm using 2.2.0